# how to try and catch for preprocessor directives like "#include"

Tags: c++, include, try-catch, preprocessor

is there a method to try and catch for an #include directive
since #include is processor directives and try catch method is done during compilation it wont work is there any workaround for it?
I need to check if a file can be included else include another file.

Comment: Since the C++17 standard there's a `__has_include` directove. See e.g. [this `#include` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) for details.

Comment: thanks i was not aware of this preprocessor directive thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__has_include function along with using #if and #elif would do that.

```
#if defined __has_include
#  if __has_include (<stdatomic.h>)
#    include <stdatomic.h>
#  endif
#endif
```

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html